# Booting encrypted disk kernel error: Cannot initialize device-mapper

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have Ubuntu 15.04 with a default full disk encryption installed on my [chromebook Pixel](https://store.google.com/product/chromebook_pixel_2015) with [linux-samus kernel patch](https://github.com/tsowell/linux-samus) and everything is working fine. I've just tried compiling a [newer version of the kernel (4.1)](https://github.com/raphael/linux-4.1-samus), but when I'm trying to boot it I'm getting an error where I would normally enter the disk encryption password:

```
Cannot initialize device-mapper. Is dm_mod kernel module loaded?
```

I'm guessing something is missing in kernel config, any idea what that is? This is the kernel [config file](http://pastebin.com/mpwgLJri).

Comment: I don't see any BLK_DEV_DM (aka «*Device Mapper Support*») in your kernel config. That sure could explain your issue.

Comment: @Nasha Should I add something like `BLK_DEV_DM=y` somewhere then?

Comment: No, definitely not. You should instead run `make menuconfig` (or `make nconfig`) and check it from there. It's under «*Device drivers*» > «*Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM)*» > «*Device mapper support*». Put a star in front of the latter.

Comment: @Nasha It works, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Device Mapper* driver is missing. Run `make nconfig` or `make menuconfig`:

```
    Device Drivers  --->
    [*] Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM)  --->
        <*>   Device mapper support
```

and recompile your kernel.